# Trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a 2011 i7 Mac Mini with broken AMD GPU

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I've been running a 2011 i7 Mac Mini for the past 5 years. I loved it!

But.. Like all laptops and Mac Minis with a AMD GPU (my Mac Mini has a AMD Radeon HD 6630M) from 2011 from Apple, it ran too hot, and my AMD GPU broke.

The Mac Mini still works fine, but only on it's HD3000 integrated GPU. No problem, as I wanted to run Ubuntu 16.04 on it anyway. However, that turned out not to be that easy... By default, the installer boots to the dedicated GPU, so I edited the boot params and inserted

```
radeon.runpm=0 radeon.modeset=0
```

and I was able to install Ubuntu fine.

The problems started when I rebooted. The purple screen... Okay, so, hold shift on boot, edit params (weird thing is that I needed to restart twice before it entered grub), and I tried all kinds of things here... If I take out `quiet splash` and replace it with

```
radeon.runpm=0 radeon.modeset=0
```

and <kbd>F10</kbd>, it stays on it's purple screen..
Adding `acpi=0` doesn't do anything, the same with `nolapic`.

So I tried things...

When I remove the gfxmode line above, I CAN see it boots, and with the

```
radeon.runpm=0 radeon.modeset=0
```

line it sometimes will even get to the login prompt. Most of the time the screen stays black, or hangs at the ethernetcard which is initialized properly on the screen.

The rare times I do get the login screen, keyboard and mouse don't work, so I can't really do anything. `nolapic` just slowed things down and didn't work, `acpi=off` did seem to have a better chance of a login screen, but still no mouse and keyboard..

By now, I'm running out of ideas... It's frustrating knowing that it installed just fine, seems to be able to boot, but can't use it...

Anyone have things I could try?

I also wonder why removing the 'gfxmode' line has a better chance of succeeding..

Comment: Is there a BIOS setting in my Mac Mini to disable the Radeon GPU? The boot options you've added don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

I used this on my 2011 MBP. Try if it works on the Mac mini.

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/installing-ubuntu-on-2011-mbp-with-failed-amd-gpu.2182103/#post-27378444

Edit:

This assumes you're using 18.4.2 LTS. Boot into the USB, when grub appears, type 'e' and edit the grub list.

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
   set gfxpayload=keep
   outb 0x728 1
   outb 0x710 2
   outb 0x740 2
   outb 0x750 0
   linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0 ---
   initrd   /casper/initrd
}
```

This should allow you to boot in to Live mode (though probably with a color-distorted screen). Install Ubuntu, don't worry about partitioning and let Ubuntu erase everything (since you are using a blank drive) and do not include 3rd party drivers. Reboot into the USB, and enter the same codes in the grub.

When the GUI comes up, open Files app> Other Locations >Computer> Boot> Grub, and look for the **grub.cfg** file. Open a Terminal and type:

`sudo chmod 777`

Then drag the grub.cfg file into the terminal window. Press enter.
[changing the file permissions to R/W](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvinZ.png)

This changes the file's permission to R/W.

Open the grub.cfg file, and look for the [menuentry 'ubuntu'] line. Below this is the [load_video] line. After this line, add

```
   outb 0x728 1
   outb 0x710 2
   outb 0x740 2
   outb 0x750 0
```

A few lines below that is the Linux kernel line. After 'quiet splash' add

```
 i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0
```

This allows you to edit the grub into this:
[Editing the grub menu entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsGXe.png)

Save the file, then do this in Terminal:

```
sudo chmod 444
```

then drag the grub file into the terminal window. If you haven't closed terminal yet, just issue the last sudo chmod command by pressing the up key and change 777 to 444. 
[changing the permissions back to read only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbSnR.png)

This assumes you didn't reboot to test if it works.

Reboot the computer. Ideally, if you did things right, it should boot directly into Ubuntu, bypassing the grub entry altogether. You can still access the grub menu by pressing option/alt.

Comment: Welcome to _Ask Ubuntu._ Please include the essential parts here.

Comment: edited. it's basically what I've done sans the anecdote.